# Why the windows server 2017 very slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have created one instance at amazon lightsail using windows server 2016, RAM 512MB and Storage 30GB configuration. When I am trying to open its terminal window using "Connect Using RDP", it is providing "connecting to yous instance" message long times. But it is not opening the terminal window.
If it will not open then I can't work.
How can solve this problem?

Comment: I have updated my instance bt taking 2GB RAM and 40 GB memory. till now after some time it is showing same error " connecting to your instance" & terminal window is not opening. any one suggest me what is happening and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

With only 512mb of memory, Windows is going to run slow.

Consider increasing your memory by snapshotting your instance, create a new instance wuith more memory from that snapshot.

IMO, 2gb is a good starting point.

Comment: how can i create a upgraded new instance from the snapshot? any one suggest me please.